# PhoneGap photo to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cordova, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a photo jpg from a PhoneGap app (javascript) to Google App Engine (php), store parameters in a db, and photo to Google Cloud Storage. All works except the photo file transfer.

The upload function I'm using is typical of PhoneGap's file transfer example http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer.

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {

    // imageURI is photo local url file:///Users/me/Library/...etc ... .jpg 
    // from navigator.camera.getPicture function 

    // prepare post variables 
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    var params = new Object();
    params.foo = "foo";
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    // upload image and option  
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, 'http://myapphere.appspot.com/php/myphoto.php', function(r){
        // do stuff with r.response
    },function(error){
        // error
    },options,true);
}
```

On the Google App Engine server, the parameter variables pass fine - what doesn't seem to transfer it the $_FILE file.

```
/* php/myphoto.php */ 

// option variables are passed - this works
$foo = $_POST["foo"];

// but it seems the $_FILES is empty? 
$gs_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];  // <-- not transferring? 
$fileName = 'test.jpg';
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($gs_name, "gs://mybucket/".$fileName);
```

A file test.jpg is stored in mybucket (a small blank binary/octet). As a test, I created an HTML form on GAE to upload a file image and move_upload_file $_FILE to mybucket, it works. It's the transfer of $_FILES from the javascript app that I can't figure out.  (I'm aware of the Google Cloud Storage JSON API objects.insert, but here I'd like to go from phonegap html/javascript to Google App Engine PHP page to process passed data).

Comment: did you print out something on the server like var_dump($_FILES["file"]) and dump it out on success/error callbacks to try ? You should try that first to make sure it's really $_FILES isn't transferring

Comment: Hey Gerry, I'm trying to set a phonegap app with photos uploaded directly to GCS, and have a hard time... Did you find what bothered you on that ? Basically I want users to be able to take pictures and those would go to GCS...